# Jquery validation bundle when use minification version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, bundle, unobtrusive-validation

In the MVC there is RegisterBundles class that we register bundles on it

there is bundle for jquery validation :

```
     bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.*"));
```

jquery.validate.* mean that load

```
 jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

I start my application in debug mode and release mode and I notes it load 
`jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

my question how to load minification version in the release mode 
jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

and why the bundle is not  from the first

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
 "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable minification even if you add non-minified version of js/css by adding

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

in your RegisterBundles method (BundleConfig class in the App_Start folder).

check [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) for more info

You could also enable it through web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
</system.web>
```

Since in release mode the debug attribute will be set as false by transformation script so I would recommend that enable the optimization by this attribute.

You can check if transformation web.Release.config is not removing the debug attribute then you can update it

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
 </system.web>
```